# Qt Application - Event posting

Tags: qt, mips

I am new to Qt. 
I have ported Qt on MIPS platform.
I have a sample application which is running (TrivialWizard) which comes along with Qt. 
I don't have Keyboard / Mouse events.

I would like to display the wizard and kill it after 5 minutes. 
after `app.exec()`, the control never comes back. 
How i can post event to kill/stop the wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a single shot timer. There is even a convenience method for that, so you should be able to use something like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTimer>
...
QTimer::singleShot( 5 * 60 * 1000, qApp, SLOT(quit()) );
```

The time delay is given in milli seconds and the slot to be called is defined in `QCoreApplication`, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit